# How do I "append" a column with a value from a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, mariadb

**Context**

I have a SQL table with the following structure:

```
# TableName
+------------+------------+
| ColumnA    | ColumnB    |
+------------+------------+
| Person A   | 2022-03-01 |
| Person B   | 2022-03-01 |
| Person C   | 2022-03-01 |
| ...        | ...        |
| Person AAA | 2022-04-12 |
| Person BBB | 2022-04-12 |
| Person CCC | 2022-04-12 |
+------------+------------+
```

I would like a query that returns all people in `ColumnA` from N days ago (call it 5),
along with the max date in `ColumnB` in the table. For example:

```
# TableName
+------------+------------+
| ColumnA    | ColumnB    |
+------------+------------+
| Person D   | 2022-04-15 | # This record's value for ColumnB = 2022-04-10
| Person E   | 2022-04-15 | # This record's value for ColumnB = 2022-04-10
| Person F   | 2022-04-15 | # This record's value for ColumnB = 2022-04-10
| Person G   | 2022-04-15 | # This record's value for ColumnB = 2022-04-10
+------------+------------+
```

**The Catch(es)**

This query is being executed via [Panda's `read_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html), so I can't do something like the following (*must be one `SELECT` statement*):

```
SET @max_date = (SELECT MAX(ColumnB) FROM TableName);

SELECT
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    @max_date
FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnB = (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        ColumnB
    FROM TableName
    ORDER BY ColumnB DESC
    LIMIT 1
    OFFSET 4
);
```

Additionally,  `ColumnB` doesn't include *all* days so I can't do something like this:

```
SELECT
    ColumnA,
    DATE_ADD(ColumnB, INTERVAL 4 DAYS) as Blah
FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnB = (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        ColumnB
    FROM TableName
    ORDER BY ColumnB DESC
    LIMIT 1
    OFFSET 4
);
```

**The Question**

How would I write such a query? Is there some way I can "append" the `MAX(ColumnB)` via a `JOIN` or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more complex/explicit

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.MaxColumnB
FROM TableName a
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(ColumnB) As MaxColumnB FROM TableName) b ON 1 = 1
WHERE a.ColumnB = (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        ColumnB
    FROM TableName
    ORDER BY ColumnB DESC
    LIMIT 1
    OFFSET 4
);
```

Comment: Boom - thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right:

```
SELECT 
    ColumnA,
    max(ColumnB) as ColumnB
FROM
    TableName
WHERE
    ColumnB >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAYS;
```